# check what type of element is present in table cell

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

using protractor I'm looping through some table cells trying to prove that a checked checkbox is present.

```
var elements = element.all(by.css(columncssname));  
elements.each(function (cell, index) {
     <--need to confirm if checkbox displayed an checked here -->
});
```

How I say is there an element here (in cell) of a type checkbox?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isDisplayed()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed) function to check if an element is displayed along with [`isSelected()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected) function to check if element is checked. Assuming there are multiple checkboxes, one in each cell, here's how to check them -

```
var elements = element.all(by.css(columncssname));
var checkboxElement = $('SUB_LOCATOR_FOR_EACH_CHECKBOX_IN_CELL');
elements.each(function (cell, index) {
    expect(cell.checkboxElement.isDisplayed()).toBe(true); //Verify checkbox is displayed
    cell.checkboxElement.isSelected().then(function(selected){
        if(selected) console.log('Element Selected'); //Prints element selection to console
    });
});
```

Another way of checking if element is checked is using [`filter()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) function to get the `count()` of checked checkboxes. Here's how -

```
var checkboxElement = element.all(by.css('LOCATOR_FOR_ALL_CHECKBOXES')); //provide a universal locator for all checkbox and not sub locator to table cell
checkboxElement.filter(function(eachCell){
    return eachCell.checkboxElement.isSelected().then(function(selected){
        return selected;
    });
}).count().then(function(count){
    console.log(count); //returns count of elements that are checked
});
```

Hope it helps